# Python SUDS - Can't generate the proper SOAP request

Tags: python, web-services, plugins, soap, suds

I am having a problem trying to generate the right soap request using SUDS.
For a certain xml element, i need to specify the attribute using the namespace:

```
ns0:type
```

The original specification is:

```
(ParameterType){
   Name =
      (NameType){
         value = None
         _required = ""
      }
   Description = None
   Value =
      (ValueType){
         Text = None
         XmlDoc = None
         _type = ""
      }
 }
```

So I get this xml:

```
 <ns0:parameters>
    <ns0:Input>
       <ns0:Parameter>
          <ns0:Name required="true">Param</ns0:Name>
          <ns0:Value type="xs:Text">
             <ns0:Text>1</ns0:Text>
          </ns0:Value>
       </ns0:Parameter>
    </ns0:Input>
 </ns0:parameters>
```

What I need to get it this one:

```
 <ns0:parameters>
    <ns0:Input>
       <ns0:Parameter>
          <ns0:Name required="true">Param</ns0:Name>
          <ns0:Value ns0:type="xs:Text">
             <ns0:Text>1</ns0:Text>
          </ns0:Value>
       </ns0:Parameter>
    </ns0:Input>
 </ns0:parameters>
```

I tried using plugins, but I guess It doesn't like the ":" char. Here is the code:

```
class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        foo = context.envelope.getChild('Body').getChild('ns0:executeProcess').getChild('ns0:parameters').getChild('ns0:Input').getChild('ns0:Parameter').getChild('ns0:Value')
        foo.attributes.append(Attribute("ns0:type", "Text"))
```

Any ideas about how can I achieve this?

More info: suds 0.4.1 - python 2.4

Answer (score 3):

I found the proper plugin use:

```
class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
def marshalled(self, context):
    inputElement = context.envelope.getChild('Body').getChild('ns0:executeProcess').getChild('ns0:parameters').getChild('ns0:Input')
    parametrosElements = inputElement.getChildren()
    for i in range( len( parametrosElements ) ):
        valueElement = parametrosElements[i].getChild('ns0:Value')
        valueElement.attributes.append(Attribute("ns0:type", "Text" ))
```